# Unknown column error in group_concat function

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm writing an event dashboard and I'm working on joining tables to build a hierarchical relationship so I can get the latest event. I'm able to get the query back from the database except for the group_concat function below. (I'm including the AutoEscalationDB class for reference, as this is how all the functions within the class are accessing the existing database. Other code in the class is redacted but it's not relevant to this problem.)

```
from app import app

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, or_, func
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.sql import expression
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, aliased, sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy.types import TIMESTAMP, INTEGER
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm.exc import FlushError
from sqlalchemy.exc import InvalidRequestError
from sqlalchemy.ext import compiler
from sqlalchemy.sql import ColumnElement
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import FunctionElement, ClauseElement

class event_id(ColumnElement):
    type = INTEGER()

class group_concat(ColumnElement):
    def __init__(self, col1, col2, separator):
        self.col1 = col1
        self.col2 = col2
        self.type = col1.type
        self.separator = separator

separator = "','"

class AutoEscalationDB(object):

    def __init__(self, host=app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'],
                 port=app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT'],
                 user=app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'],
                 passwd=app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'],
                 db=app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'],
                 short_retry=5, lifetime_retry=25,
                 socket=app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_SOCKET']):

        self.URI = 'mysql://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s?unix_socket=%s' %(user, passwd, host, port, db, socket)
        self.create_model()
        session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = scoped_session(session_factory)
        self.methods = {
            1: self.Emails,
            2: self.Phones,
        }

    @compiler.compiles(group_concat, 'mysql')
    def compile_group_concat(element, compiler, **kw):
        return "GROUP_CONCAT(%s ORDER BY %s SEPARATOR %s)" % (
                    compiler.process(element.col1),
                    compiler.process(element.col2),
                    separator
               )

   def get_escalations(self, event_id=None, **kwargs):
        es1 = aliased(self.Event_statuses)
        es2 = aliased(self.Event_statuses)
        e1 = aliased(self.Events)
        e2 = aliased(self.Events)
        m = MetaData()
        separator = "','"
        t = Table('e2', m, Column('event_id', Integer), Column('event_id', Integer))
        eid = group_concat(t.c.event_id, t.c.event_id, ',').compile(bind=create_engine('mysql://'))
        query = self.session.query(e1).\
            from_self(e1.parent_event_id,
                e1.event_id,
                es1.event_status,
                e1.event_name,
                eid.string,
                e1.reporter,
                e1.message,
                self.Users.user_id,
                self.Users.username,
                self.Users.first_name,
                self.Users.last_name,
                e1.timestamp
            ).outerjoin(e2, e2.parent_event_id == e1.event_id).\
            join(es1, es1.event_statuses_id == e1.event_status_id).\
            outerjoin(es2, e2.event_status_id == es2.event_statuses_id).\
            outerjoin(self.Users, self.Users.user_id == e1.user_id)

        results = {}

        for row in query:
            row = row._asdict()
            if row['event_status'] in results.keys():
                results[row['event_status']].append(row)
            else:
                results[row['event_status']] = [row]

        return True, results
```

When I hit the URL I get this error:

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown
column 'e2.event_id' in 'field list'") [SQL: u"SELECT
anon_1.events_1_parent_event_id AS anon_1_events_1_parent_event_id,
anon_1.events_1_event_id AS anon_1_events_1_event_id,
event_statuses_1.event_status AS event_statuses_1_event_status,
anon_1.events_1_event_name AS anon_1_events_1_event_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(e2.event_id ORDER BY e2.event_id SEPARATOR ','),
anon_1.events_1_reporter AS anon_1_events_1_reporter, 
anon_1.events_1_message AS anon_1_events_1_message, users.user_id AS 
users_user_id, users.username AS users_username, users.first_name AS  
users_first_name, users.last_name AS users_last_name, 
anon_1.events_1_timestamp AS anon_1_events_1_timestamp \nFROM (SELECT 
events_1.event_id AS events_1_event_id, events_1.event_type_id AS 
events_1_event_type_id, events_1.reporter AS events_1_reporter, 
events_1.parent_event_id AS events_1_parent_event_id, 
events_1.property_id AS events_1_property_id, events_1.event_name AS 
events_1_event_name, events_1.event_status_id AS 
events_1_event_status_id, events_1.escalation_type_id AS 
events_1_escalation_type_id, events_1.timestamp AS events_1_timestamp, 
events_1.user_id AS events_1_user_id, events_1.message AS 
events_1_message, events_1.group_id AS events_1_group_id, 
events_1.shift_id AS events_1_shift_id \nFROM events AS events_1) AS 
anon_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN events AS events_2 ON events_2.parent_event_id =
anon_1.events_1_event_id INNER JOIN event_statuses AS event_statuses_1 ON 
event_statuses_1.event_statuses_id = anon_1.events_1_event_status_id LEFT 
OUTER JOIN event_statuses AS event_statuses_2 ON events_2.event_status_id
= event_statuses_2.event_statuses_id LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON 
users.user_id = anon_1.events_1_user_id"]
```

If I comment out eid.string, it returns the query as it should:

```
SELECT anon_1.events_1_parent_event_id AS
anon_1_events_1_parent_event_id, anon_1.events_1_event_id AS 
anon_1_events_1_event_id, event_statuses_1.event_status AS 
event_statuses_1_event_status, anon_1.events_1_event_name AS 
anon_1_events_1_event_name, anon_1.events_1_reporter AS 
anon_1_events_1_reporter, anon_1.events_1_message AS 
anon_1_events_1_message, users.user_id AS users_user_id, users.username 
AS users_username, users.first_name AS users_first_name, users.last_name 
AS users_last_name, anon_1.events_1_timestamp AS 
anon_1_events_1_timestamp 
FROM (SELECT events_1.event_id AS events_1_event_id, 
events_1.event_type_id AS events_1_event_type_id, events_1.reporter AS 
events_1_reporter, events_1.parent_event_id AS events_1_parent_event_id,
events_1.property_id AS events_1_property_id, events_1.event_name AS 
events_1_event_name, events_1.event_status_id AS 
events_1_event_status_id, events_1.escalation_type_id AS 
events_1_escalation_type_id, events_1.timestamp AS events_1_timestamp, 
events_1.user_id AS events_1_user_id, events_1.message AS 
events_1_message, events_1.group_id AS events_1_group_id, 
events_1.shift_id AS events_1_shift_id 
FROM events AS events_1) AS anon_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN events AS events_2 ON 
events_2.parent_event_id = anon_1.events_1_event_id JOIN event_statuses
AS event_statuses_1 ON event_statuses_1.event_statuses_id = 
anon_1.events_1_event_status_id LEFT OUTER JOIN event_statuses AS
event_statuses_2 ON events_2.event_status_id =
event_statuses_2.event_statuses_id LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.user_id = anon_1.events_1_user_id
```

And if I stick in a 'print eid' statement, it returns this, which *should* be right:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(e2.event_id ORDER BY e2.event_id SEPARATOR ',')
```

The SQL query I'm attempting to replicate is this:

```
SELECT
e1.parent_event_id,
e1.event_id,
es1.event_status,
e1.event_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(e2.event_id ORDER BY e2.event_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS child_events,
e1.reporter,
e1.message,
u1.user_id,
u1.username,
u1.first_name,
u1.last_name,
e1.timestamp
FROM events e1
LEFT JOIN events e2 ON (e2.parent_event_id = e1.event_id)
JOIN event_statuses es1 ON (es1.event_statuses_id = e1.event_status_id)
LEFT JOIN event_statuses es2 ON (es2.event_statuses_id = e2.event_status_id)
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON (u1.user_id = e1.user_id);
```

I have confirmed the query itself works.

I suspect this part of the group_concat statement:

```
.compile(bind=create_engine('mysql://'))
```

is creating a new mysql engine instead of binding to the existing database and is therefore unable to find the event_id column from the Events table. Unfortunately this isn't my code and I'm new to sqlalchemy so I'm sort of shooting in the dark. Any suggestions would be most welcome, as I've been plugging away at this for a few days and I'm stuck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ask in SQLAlchemy's IRC channel? I'm not sure about your use of session.query(...).from_self(...). Could be related. Did you try to render the query via the "core" API, i.e. select([columns]).select_from(fromexpr).where(whereclause)?

Comment: I did ask in the IRC channel but it's been pretty quiet in there. The session.query statement pulls from the database without my having to set up a new connection. I'm able to get the rows out of the database if I do a plain `text()` statement, but I'd rather not go that route, as of course it's less flexible.